# :hover активен тогда когда нет касания на тачскринах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

К элементу выставлен :hover, собственно при наведении курсора мыши он работает, свойства элемента возвращаются на исходные тогда когда курсор уводят с него.

Но когда на тачскринах кликаешь по элементу, свойства присваиваются, а вот обратно не возвращаются.

Возвращаются тогда когда было последующее косание и не по элементу.

Есть ли решение на сегодня этому?

Comment: Видимо размер элемента не задан точно

Comment: а вы на тач скринах курсором на элемент заезжаете?

Comment: Потому что так на телефонах это и работает. Курсора же нет.

Comment: Что на смартфонах работает точно так же как hover при курсоре?